# Can I create a 1 MB mobile application with Ionic 3 (Information)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Can I create a 1 MB mobile application with Ionic 3? I also want to use plugins like social sharing, file, file transfer, network information, camera, statusbar, etc.

Comment: You should read the ionic 3 documentation. Here you must post your code sample and not a generic information question.

Comment: command to reduce your app size : `ionic cordova build [<platform>]  --prod --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs` more details https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/

Comment: Thank you kishore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible. Ionic requires at least Angular and Cordova in order to run on real devices. The size of both of them is more than 2 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a 1 MB app using Ionic. It should have at least a 3 MB file size.

Comment: are you sure sir

Comment: yeh 3.42mb final apk for me